# XSLT how to use mode to allow multiple apply-template matches to replace characters in text?

Tags: xml, xslt, mode

I tried to use modes to run multiple apply-templates for replacing characters in the XML text (e.g. replacing " ' < > with space). But it's not successful. Please help.

Codes in the picture

[image]

Comment: Please post your code **as code**, not as a picture, and include an example of the input and the expected output - see: [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to post the code as code, however it couldn't recognize the full code, so I had to post a picture.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems, your template with `match="*/text()"` without any mode matches text nodes but then all the `apply-templates` you have inside have `select="*/text()"` so you try, with a text node as the template's context node, to select the text node grandchildren of any element children, which never makes sense, as any text node is a leaf node and certainly doesn't contain any element nodes with further text nodes; therefore, in the template for matched `text()` node, if you want to apply-templates to the node itself in a different mode, you need `<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="foo"/>`.

As for applying several modes, I suspect you want to chain them and not apply all of them separately. For such chaining, you would need to use variables e.g. `<xsl:variable name="step1"><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="m1"/></xsl:variable><xsl:apply-templates select="$step1/node()" mode="m2"/>`, which, unfortunately, in XSLT 1 would additionally require the use of an extension function like `exsl:node-set` on any variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="step1"><xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="m1"/></xsl:variable><xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($step1)/node()" mode="m2"/>`.

Looking at the task you want to solve it seems much easier to just use `translate` once with e.g. `<xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="translate(., concat(&quot;'&quot;, '&quot;&lt;&gt;'), '    ')"/></xsl:template>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My goal is to learn how to apply multiple templates to the same nodes in a particular order. I heard "mode" can help. The way you chain the modes is useful, but I don't quite understand the code, as I'm new to this. If using XSLT 2 or 3, would it be better? Thanks!